# Extract data from Word File in Python

Tags: python, python-docx

I want to extract the following word file data using Python in such a way that the subject and body are stored in separate variables. The text 'subject' and 'body' should be excluded. For body, there should be a space after 'Hi (name)', and then comes the actual para and after that a space followed by salutation. The word file looks like this:
[image]

So I have performed this:

```
doc = docx.Document("sample email.docx")
all_paras = doc.paragraphs
subjectPara = doc.paragraphs[0].text
subjectIndex = subjectPara.find(":")
Subject = subjectPara[subjectIndex + 1 : -1].strip()
print(Subject)
```

But the output for this is:

```
Introducing: “TikTok 4 Realtors” Packag
```

It is excluding the last letter 'e' for some reason and I have no idea why.

Another problem is when I am doing the following for body:

```
doc = docx.Document("sample email.docx")
body = ""
all_paras = doc.paragraphs
for para in all_paras:
  if para != all_paras[0] and para.text.strip() != "Body:":
    body = body + '\n' + para.text
print(body.lstrip())
```

And the result that I am getting is as follows:

```
Hi (name),
Please take a look at our new website: TikTok4Realtors.com.
Best Regards,
James O.
CEO/Founder
```

The problem here is with the spaces that I require.

Comment: `subjectPara[subjectIndex + 1:].strip()` should solve your first problem. Which "spaces" are missing? I dont see it. Do you mean the blank lines in the image of your source docx?

Comment: Thanks it worked. I want to add a line space after 'Hi (name),' which i now managed but how do i get a line space before 'Best Regards' or any other salutation word?